# How to remove Microsoft-IIS/8.5 header from Response headers in a shared server

Tags: iis, server, header, response, hosting

I want to remove Microsoft-IIS/8.5 header. Most of the tutorials online are suggesting to use IIS manager to fix the issue, but my server provider is not allowing IIS manager in their shared server. How to remove the server version without using IIS manager.

Comment: You don't have enough options on IIS 8.5, https://blog.lextudio.com/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be

Comment: Does your server include UrlRewrite module? If so you can use an outbound rule to modify headers with just your web.config.

Answer (score 1):

If yoy want to remove unwanted http response headers with out iis, you can try the following two methods:

1. Using the Registry key

   Create a DWORD entry called DisableServerHeader in the following Registry key and set the value to 1.

   **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters**. After adding the Registry key, restart the HTTP service using the net stop http command and the net start http command. If the HTTP service doesn’t start up then use the iisreset command. If that also doesn’t work then you can restart the server.
2. Using the URLScan tool.

   You need to install the URLScan in your machine. After installing URLScan, open the URLScan.ini file typically located in the **%WINDIR%\System32\Inetsrv\URLscan** folder. After opening it, search for the key RemoveServerHeader . By default it is set to 0, but to remove the Server header, change the value to 1.Doing so will remove the Server header Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 from the User mode response.

Comment: How to do these things? All I have access to is the Plesk control panel of the shared server.

Comment: If there is only Plesk control panel, it cannot be done.